# SQL: Flatten hierarchy with missing levels

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, pivot

I have a table with a parent-child hierarchy together with a column that tells on which hierarchy level the current id is.

An example:

```
id   pid    level
A             H1
B     A       H2
C     B       H3
D     C       H4 
E             H1
F     E       H3
G     F       H4
```

I want this to be transposed or flatten creating two rows one for each id on the lowest level.

Like this:

```
id    H1    H2    H3    H4
D     A     B     C     D
G     E           F     G
```

Can you do it in SQL using pivot? I was thinking that maybe the value of the "level" column could be used as name for the columns in the result table? Value "H1" maps to column name "H1" and so on.

Stored procedure would also be a possible solution that I could think of. Anyone who have done something like this?

Thanks for your help!

/Andreas

Comment: Are you limited to 4 levels?

Comment: @GordonLinoff It is a limit, I think it is 8 or 9 levels. But levels in between can be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a table ttt that contains your data. This query will pivot five levels for you:

```
select id
     , [H1], [H2], [H3], [H4], [H5]
from
( 
  select distinct
         coalesce(c6.id,c5.id,c4.id,c3.id,c2.id,c1.id) as id
       , c1.id as lid
       , c1.level 
    from ttt c1
    left join ttt c2
      on c1.id = c2.pid
    left join ttt c3
      on c2.id = c3.pid
    left join ttt c4
      on c3.id = c4.pid
    left join ttt c5
      on c4.id = c5.pid
    left join ttt c6
      on c5.id = c6.pid ) as sourcetable
  pivot ( max(lid) 
    for level in ([H1], [H2], [H3], [H4], [H5])
    ) as pivottable;
```

you can check it out at sqlfiddle: [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9dacf7/1)

Comment: Thanks Brett! Worked fantastic!